# Searching a list of strings for all items of a string

Tags: python, string, for-loop, find, iteration

I am trying to determine whether all elements of search_string are present in one of the strings in the list look_here_string. For efficiency reasons, if one element is not present, the word is removed from the list.

```
search_string = '1abc'
look_here_string = ['dedakloera', 'tuau', '1abcdefg']
x = 0
counter = 0

for item in search_string:
    item = search_string[counter]
    #print item, search_string, look_here_string[x]
    if not item in look_here_string[x]:
        print item, 'not in', look_here_string[x]
        look_here_string.remove(look_here_string[x])
        counter = 0
    else:
        print item, 'in', look_here_string[x]
        counter +=1
```

This is the output I am looking for:

```
1 not in dedakloera    
1 not in tuau          
1 in 1abcdefg          
a in 1abcdefg          
b in 1abcdefg          
c in 1abcdefg
```

This is the output I get:

```
1 not in dedakloera    #correct
1 not in tuau          #correct
1 in 1abcdefg          #correct
a in 1abcdefg          #correct
```

It seems that the script is stopping prematurely, but I can't figure out what's wrong in my code. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Because you have used `for item in search_string:`, which would only iterate for n = len(search_string), hence printing the output only 4 times.

Comment: How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simple approach is to iterate through `look_here_string` in outer loop

```
search_string = '1abc'
look_here_string = ['dedakloera', 'tuau', '1abcdefg']
ind_to_remove = []
for i,s in enumerate(look_here_string):
    for e in search_string:
        if not e in s:
            ind_to_remove.append(i)
            print e, 'not in', s
            break
        else:
            print e, 'in', s
for i in ind_to_remove[::-1]:
    del look_here_string[i]
```

Comment: Thank you for this input: If I understand your code correctly, you construct a list of indices of the absent strings first and then remove the items from look_here_string based on this list. This helped a lot!

Comment: @Johannes Schwaninger You are welcome) And yes, you understand all correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could write this even more concisely using the "all" builtin function and a list comprehension:

```
>>> search_string = '1abc'
>>> look_here_string = ['dedakloera', 'tuau', '1abcdefg']
>>> [string for string in look_here_string 
            if all(char in string for char in search_string)]
```

This creates a new list, but it will filter invalid strings automatically.

Comment: very concise code! - thanks for suggestion to use "all"